# Pass List and find it from a string

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to pass List of string and get the count of it from another string.

Example : String is life is easy and is complicated.

From this i want the count of is from the string which is 3.I have got the solution of this which is

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s1;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the String : ");
        s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(counting.StringMatch(s1, "is"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static class counting
    {
        public static int StringMatch(string text, string pattern)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) != -1)
            {
                i += pattern.Length;
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }`
```

Now as I have passed only one value that is "is" it works fine how do I pass more than one value that is "is" "and" I tried to pass list of string.

```
 public static void Main()
    {
        string s1;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the String : ");
        s1 = Console.ReadLine();

        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("or");
        lst.Add("the");
        Console.WriteLine(counting.StringMatch(s1, lst));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static class counting
    {
        public static int StringMatch(string text,  List<string> pattern)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = text.IndexOf(pattern, i)) != -1)
            {
                i += pattern.Length;
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Getting errors may be this the wrong way of doing it,how do I deal with this situation.

Comment: "Getting errors" - what errors, and where? Do you understand the error? *Never* just say you're getting errors... *always* say what they are. (Additionally, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions - and it's not clear why you even want a separate class for `StringMatch`.)

Comment: As i know _IndexOf_ function gets only string (or char) as input not a list. Can you compile your code?

Answer (score 1):

The `String.IndexOf` method doesn't have any overload that takes any kind of collection of strings. You need a method that looks for each string in the list and returns the one that is first:

```
public static class counting {

  private static int IndexOf(string text, List<string> pattern, int startIndex, out string match) {
    int firstIndex = -1;
    match = null;
    foreach (string s in pattern) {
      int index = text.IndexOf(s, startIndex);
      if (index != -1 && (firstIndex == -1 || index < firstIndex)) {
        firstIndex = index;
        match = s;
      }
    }
    return firstIndex;
  }

  public static int StringMatch(string text, List<string> pattern) {
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    string match;
    while ((i = IndexOf(text, pattern, i, out match)) != -1) {
      i += match.Length;
      count++;
    }
    return count;
  }

}
```